# Trying to convert list values to float in a dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data where some of the columns are list values. I am trying to convert them to floats but nothing works. I tried these:

```
df["name_tokens"]=df["name_tokens"].apply(lambda x:x[0])
df["name_tokens"]=df["name_tokens"].convert_dtypes(convert_floating=True)
```

It converts to a string:

```
id                   float64
name_tokens           string
ingredient_tokens     object
steps_tokens          object
techniques            object
ingredient_ids        object
recipe_id              int64
rating                 int64
labels                 int32
dtype: object
```

But the data looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The items in the `name_tokens` columns are actually strings, so neither of your solutions will get you anywhere. `.apply(lambda x:x[0])` is *almost* right, but the reason you're getting `[` as the value for all the columns is that `x[0]` like that bascially returns the first (0th) character of each row, which is `[`.

Instead, use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the strings to Python arrays, and use `.str[0]` to get the first item of each array:

```
import ast
df['name_tokens'] = df['name_tokens'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0]
```